# what is the wrong in this code when i coding signup form

Tags: php

What is the problem in this code

I want to when you User sign up to put personal information with personal photo

Code was working before adding upload photos

```
if(isset($_POST['registerdo'])){
if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)){
        $Dbadduser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user
        (u_name,u_pass,u_email,u_lv,name,file,type,size)
        VALUES
        ('$name','$pass','$email','1','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')
         ")or die(mysql_error());
         }
      if(isset($Dbadduser)){
        echo"
        <div class='success'>register successful </div><br/>
           ";

        include"files/block.php"; 
        include"files/footer.php";
        exit;
      }
```

}

Comment: Might be the backslashes in the file path?  You need to parameterize your SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert into 8 columns, but you're only giving the query 7 values:

**The query:**

```
("INSERT INTO user (u_name,u_pass,u_email,u_lv,name,file,type,size) VALUES ('$name','$pass','$email','1','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')
```

Either remove the column you're not inserting anything into or give the query an empty value to work with, it should work after that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you am remove it 
$Dbadduser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(u_name,u_pass,u_email,u_lv,file,type,size)VALUES('$name','$pass','$email','1','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')